# When predicting in R Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r

I have rerun the model successfully but when it comes to predictions, I don't know why the error of the atomic vector arises. Could anyone suggest...?

This is my code :

```
> #Algo
> #Regressor 
> regressor=lm(Accepectance.Rate~.,train_set) summary(regressor)
> 
> #newModel rerun 
> new_model=lm(Accepectance.Rate~GRE.Score+LOR+CGPA+Research.Paper,train_set)
> summary(new_model)
> 
> #Prediction
>
> accepectance_rate_pred=predict(new_model,test_set)

Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You appear to have commented out your model fitting and prediction steps.  Might that have something to do with the problem?  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: This is hhow I have split the data   :                                                        
                                                                                                               
library(caTools)
set.seed(7)
sample=sample.split(dataClean$Accepectance.Rate,SplitRatio = 0.80)
train_set=subset(dataClean,sample==TRUE)
test_set=subset(dataClean,sample==FALSE)                                                                                               
              ////Whereas Accepectance.Rate is an depended  variable(output)

Answer (score 0):

I implemented your code on a simulated dataset in the same format of your dataset 
There is no problem with your codes,
And it worked. 
Also I as this error indicates, it would occur when you use `$`. But here there is nothing wrong.
please check your dataset again.
If it did not resolved, post your dataset in a `dput` format.

```
library(caTools)
set.seed(7) 

dataClean <- data.frame(
  GRE.Score = sample(300:400, 400, replace = TRUE),
  TOEFL.Score = sample(100:150, 400, replace = TRUE),
  University.Rating = sample(1:5, 400, replace = TRUE),
  SOP = sample(seq(1,5,0.5), 400, replace = TRUE),
  LOR = sample(seq(1,5,0.5), 400, replace = TRUE),
  CGPA = sample(seq(5,10, 0.2), 400, replace = TRUE),
  Research.Paper = as.integer(sample(c(0,1),400, replace = TRUE)),
  Accepectance.Rate = sample(seq(0,1,0.1), 400, replace = TRUE)
  
)


sample <- sample.split(dataClean$Accepectance.Rate,SplitRatio = 0.80) 
train_set <- subset(dataClean,sample==TRUE)
test_set <- subset(dataClean,sample==FALSE) 

regressor <- lm(Accepectance.Rate~.,train_set) 
summary(regressor)

## 
## Call:
## lm(formula = Accepectance.Rate ~ ., data = train_set)
## 
## Residuals:
##      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
## -0.54706 -0.26964  0.00201  0.24565  0.54318 
## 
## Coefficients:
##                     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
## (Intercept)        0.6094121  0.2850739   2.138   0.0333 *
## GRE.Score         -0.0006321  0.0005840  -1.082   0.2799  
## TOEFL.Score        0.0009169  0.0011388   0.805   0.4213  
## University.Rating -0.0033803  0.0127747  -0.265   0.7915  
## SOP                0.0012229  0.0129978   0.094   0.9251  
## LOR               -0.0065269  0.0136695  -0.477   0.6334  
## CGPA               0.0004632  0.0109964   0.042   0.9664  
## Research.Paper     0.0346503  0.0345165   1.004   0.3162  
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
## 
## Residual standard error: 0.3072 on 312 degrees of freedom
## Multiple R-squared:  0.01007,    Adjusted R-squared:  -0.01214 
## F-statistic: 0.4533 on 7 and 312 DF,  p-value: 0.8676


new_model <- lm(Accepectance.Rate ~ GRE.Score + LOR + CGPA + Research.Paper ,train_set)
summary(new_model)


## 
## Call:
## lm(formula = Accepectance.Rate ~ GRE.Score + LOR + CGPA + Research.Paper, 
##     data = train_set)
## 
## Residuals:
##      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
## -0.54262 -0.26963  0.00716  0.25568  0.54976 
## 
## Coefficients:
##                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
## (Intercept)     0.7269863  0.2306067   3.152  0.00177 **
## GRE.Score      -0.0006560  0.0005805  -1.130  0.25931   
## LOR            -0.0070118  0.0135482  -0.518  0.60514   
## CGPA            0.0004703  0.0109438   0.043  0.96575   
## Research.Paper  0.0325429  0.0342347   0.951  0.34254   
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
## 
## Residual standard error: 0.306 on 315 degrees of freedom
## Multiple R-squared:  0.007735,   Adjusted R-squared:  -0.004865 
## F-statistic: 0.6139 on 4 and 315 DF,  p-value: 0.6529



accepectance_rate_pred=predict(new_model,test_set)

accepectance_rate_pred
##         2         4         7         8        13        33        34        37 
## 0.5011383 0.4990222 0.4573676 0.5329046 0.4963765 0.4345006 0.4746097 0.4629897 
##        44        46        47        56        58        59        71        74 
## 0.4706525 0.5053724 0.4796888 0.4628440 0.4875494 0.4815865 0.4879609 0.4788356 
##        75        77        79        80        85        89        90        93 
## 0.5172001 0.4976722 0.5005901 0.4942156 0.5287900 0.4904813 0.5095863 0.4959813 
##       102       104       109       125       129       135       140       143 
## 0.4659923 0.4491025 0.4963151 0.5092688 0.4877304 0.5018483 0.4846034 0.4978065 
##       145       147       149       150       152       168       176       183 
## 0.5166381 0.4816078 0.5095673 0.4626135 0.4948387 0.4902441 0.5123985 0.5345014 
##       188       191       194       199       213       223       224       226 
## 0.4925368 0.5149285 0.4407740 0.5316186 0.4759644 0.4849045 0.4574967 0.5504905 
##       230       233       241       249       252       254       256       259 
## 0.4503535 0.4906580 0.4821434 0.5278142 0.4977125 0.4655410 0.4939332 0.5002965 
##       260       261       266       267       272       273       283       299 
## 0.4961644 0.4629240 0.4823906 0.5203461 0.5106536 0.4544564 0.4812053 0.4951322 
##       303       304       308       320       328       333       336       340 
## 0.4900534 0.5207763 0.4641560 0.5168828 0.4968981 0.4894914 0.5245807 0.4987471 
##       341       345       360       369       384       385       392       399 
## 0.5128851 0.4705092 0.5288791 0.4783277 0.4852167 0.5244540 0.4694184 0.5380237
```

Comment: I Don't know why but it was working fine and again the same error occurs. But thanks for your help, I tried with the dataframe but it is throwing the same error $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors....Dataset should be load in dataframe rght?

Comment: Write this: dput(dataClean), then post the result by edditing your question